# OctoberCms. How to add attribute to Model?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I need display list child models by parrent model id:
it's work if i use this in model:

```
public function getIdAttribute($id)
{
  $sales = Sale::where('category_id',$id)->get();

    foreach ($sales as $sale) {
        $clean_fields[$sale->attributes['id']]['name'] = $sale->attributes['name'];
        $clean_fields[$sale->attributes['id']]['price'] = $sale->attributes['price'];
    }

    return $clean_fields;
}
```

Display list in template:

```
{% for service in servicesList %}

   <h1>{{service.name}}</h1>
   <ul class="children_list">
     {% for children in service.id %}
       <li>{{children.name}}</li>
     {% endfor %}
   <ul>

{% endfor %}
```

i modified attribute id into array. It's work in template, but in backend i have error, because id not passed to list controller. How i can get child models in component template?

Comment: The `id` attribute is most likely the primary key for your model, so you should not override the getter, unless you're going to provide an alternative means for identifying the model.

Comment: @fubar, I understand. What are the alternatives?

Comment: I'd suggest naming your `getIdAttribute` function something different, so that you're not overriding the `id` attribute getter. From the looks of the function, it doesn't look like it has anything to do with getting the `id` anyway, so the current name doesn't seem very intuitive or appropriate.

Comment: @fubar, Then how do I get the current model id?

Comment: You can just access it using the `id` property - `$model->id`

Comment: From the small snippet you've posted, it isn't clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @fubar, I added the template code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are having 2 models `Service`(parent) and `Sale`(it's child)

> I am also assuming from `template for loop` that, it is `hasMany` relation (where `service` has many records of `sale`)

where `Sale` is having `category_id` which is `id` of parent.

so inside parent model you can define relation

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public $hasMany = [
        'sales' => ['Acme\Blog\Models\Sale', 'key' => 'category_id']
        // here you need to add proper namespace for your model
    ];
}
```

now when you need to fetch relative records of `Sale` you can call this relation alias `sales`.

we assume that we are passing `servicesList` from component.

```
public function onRun()
{
    $this->page['servicesList'] = Service::all();
}
```

now inside page you can write something like this as `servicesList` will be available to page (its collection of model of `Service`)

```
{% for service in servicesList %}    
   <h1>{{service.name}}</h1>
   <ul class="children_list">
     {% for children in service.sales %} 
       <!-- its relation name 'service.sales' which we defined in model -->
       <li>{{children.name}}</li>
     {% endfor %}
   <ul>    
{% endfor %}
```

if you have any further doubt please let me know in comments.

Answer (score 0):

add proper relationship  to your model

```
 public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class,'category_id','id');
}
```

then you have the children do whatever you want

```
$model = Model::with('children')->find('id');

@foreach($model->children as $child)

@endforeach
```

Comment: Whilst this will point OP in the correct direction, relationships are declared differently in OctoberCMS than in Laravel.